# From tiff file extract values with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have download a tiff file with elevation from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp and I try to export in file text or Excel the coordinates and the elevation and I don't know how to export this data in text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QGIS select Raster/Conversion/Translate (Convert format) ... from the menu. Select the  ASCII Gridded XYZ file type and set the output file.
It will execute a gdal_translate command as you can see it in the dialog.
gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tif output.xyz

Note: it will use the raster value of the first band as Z value if you have a multiband image (e.g. RGB).

Comment: I cant find the Translate in qgis http://postimg.org/image/oe5h1avp9/

Comment: Enable GDALTools plugin in the  `Plugins/Manage and Install plugins` dialog.

Comment: The final step, then, is to import the .xyz file into Excel. Excel treats the xyz file as a text file and uses the import wizard to allow you to set the delimiters. It seems obvious now, but it took me a little time to work that out.